# Error al agregar datos en base de datos Access

Tags: c#, wpf

Les paso a explicar. Soy nuevo en lo que respecta a programación en C# y como desafio y proyecto personal me puse la meta de hacer un asistente personal. Este asistente se conecta a una base de datos de Access. En el menú de los comandos tengo distintos botones que conducen a distintas tablas de la base de datos; sociales, apps, carpetas, paginas webs y sistema. El problema es que cuando el usuario quiere agregar el comando que desee, ya sea de sociales, apps, carpetas, paginas webs o sistema, siempre se termina agregando en la tabla de sociales.

Aqui les dejo el codigo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using WpfAV.Properties;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WpfAV
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para VentanaComandos.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class VentanaComandos : Window
    {
        public ArrayList listaComandos = new ArrayList();
        OleDbConnection con;
        OleDbDataAdapter adapS, adapC, adapA, adapPW, adapSis;
        OleDbCommandBuilder cmdb;
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        DataSet ds;
        string tipo = "Sociales";
        bool CeldaIngresada = false;


        public VentanaComandos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CargarDatos();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OcultarId();
        }

        private void BtnCerrar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DragMove();
        }

        private void CargarDatos()
        {
            if (tipo == "Sociales")
            {
                Cargar_CmdSociales();
            }
            else if (tipo == "Apps")
            {
                Cargar_CmdApps();
            }
            else if (tipo == "Carpetas")
            {
                Cargar_CmdCarpetas();
            }
            else if (tipo == "Paginas webs")
            {
                Cargar_CmdWebs();
            }
            else
            {
                Cargar_CmdSistema();
            }

        }

        void Cargar_CmdSociales()
        {
            try
            {
                con = new OleDbConnection(Settings.Default.conexion);
                con.Open();
                adapS = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Id, Comando, Accion, Respuesta FROM CmdSociales", con);
                ds = new DataSet();
                adapS.Fill(ds);
                dataGridP.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        void Cargar_CmdApps()
        {
            try
            {
                con = new OleDbConnection(Settings.Default.conexion);
                con.Open();
                adapA = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Id, Comando, Accion, Respuesta FROM CmdApps", con);
                ds = new DataSet();
                adapA.Fill(ds);
                dataGridP.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        void Cargar_CmdCarpetas()
        {
            try
            {
                con = new OleDbConnection(Settings.Default.conexion);
                con.Open();
                adapC = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Id, Comando, Accion, Respuesta FROM CmdCarpetas", con);
                ds = new DataSet();
                adapC.Fill(ds);
                dataGridP.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        void Cargar_CmdWebs()
        {
            try
            {
                con = new OleDbConnection(Settings.Default.conexion);
                con.Open();
                adapPW = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Id, Comando, Accion, Respuesta FROM CmdWebs", con);
                ds = new DataSet();
                adapPW.Fill(ds);
                dataGridP.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        void Cargar_CmdSistema()
        {
            try
            {
                con = new OleDbConnection(Settings.Default.conexion);
                con.Open();
                adapSis = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Id, Comando, Accion, Respuesta FROM CmdSistema", con);
                ds = new DataSet();
                adapSis.Fill(ds);
                dataGridP.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void BtnSociales_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Cargar_CmdSociales();
            OcultarId();
        }

        private void BtnCarpetas_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Cargar_CmdCarpetas();
            OcultarId();
        }

        private void BtnApps_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Cargar_CmdApps();
            OcultarId();
        }

        private void BtnWebs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Cargar_CmdWebs();
            OcultarId();
        }

        private void BtnSistema_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Cargar_CmdSistema();
            OcultarId();
        }

        private void BtnAddComandos_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                AgregarComandosBD();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        void AgregarComandosBD()
        {
            if (tipo == "Sociales")
            {
                con = new OleDbConnection(Settings.Default.conexion);
                con.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("INSERT INTO CmdSociales (Comando, Accion, Respuesta) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", tbxComando.Text, tbxRutaAccion.Text, tbxRespuesta.Text), con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                ActualizarTabla();
                CargarDatos();
                LimpiarDatos();

            }
            else if (tipo == "Carpetas")
            {
                con = new OleDbConnection(Settings.Default.conexion);
                con.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("INSERT INTO CmdCarpetas (Comando, Accion, Respuesta) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", tbxComando.Text, tbxRutaAccion.Text, tbxRespuesta.Text), con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                ActualizarTabla();
                CargarDatos();
                LimpiarDatos();
            }
            else if (tipo == "Apps")
            {
                con = new OleDbConnection(Settings.Default.conexion);
                con.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("INSERT INTO CmdApps (Comando, Accion, Respuesta) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", tbxComando.Text, tbxRutaAccion.Text, tbxRespuesta.Text), con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                ActualizarTabla();
                CargarDatos();
                LimpiarDatos();
            }
            else if (tipo == "Paginas webs")
            {
                con = new OleDbConnection(Settings.Default.conexion);
                con.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("INSERT INTO CmdWebs (Comando, Accion, Respuesta) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", tbxComando.Text, tbxRutaAccion.Text, tbxRespuesta.Text), con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                ActualizarTabla();
                CargarDatos();
                LimpiarDatos();
            }
            else
            {
                con = new OleDbConnection(Settings.Default.conexion);
                con.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("INSERT INTO CmdSistema (Comando, Accion, Respuesta) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", tbxComando.Text, tbxRutaAccion.Text, tbxRespuesta.Text), con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                ActualizarTabla();
                CargarDatos();
                LimpiarDatos();
            }

            OcultarId();
        }

        void LimpiarDatos()
        {
            tbxComando.Text = string.Empty;
            tbxRutaAccion.Text = string.Empty;
            tbxRespuesta.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        void ActualizarTabla()
        {
            try
            {
                if (tipo == "Sociales")
                {
                    cmdb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapS);
                    adapS.Update(ds);
                }
                else if (tipo == "Carpetas")
                {
                    cmdb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapC);
                    adapC.Update(ds);
                }
                else if (tipo == "Apps")
                {
                    cmdb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapA);
                    adapA.Update(ds);
                }
                else if (tipo == "Paginas webs")
                {
                    cmdb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapPW);
                    adapPW.Update(ds);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmdb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapSis);
                    adapSis.Update(ds);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void BtnDeleteComando_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BorrarDatos();
            ActualizarTabla();
            CargarDatos();
            OcultarId();
        }

        void BorrarDatos()
        {
            List<DataRow> TheRows = new List<DataRow>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridP.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                Object o = dataGridP.SelectedItems[i];
                if (o != CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder)
                {
                    DataRowView r = (DataRowView)o;
                    TheRows.Add(r.Row);
                }
            }

            foreach (DataRow r in TheRows)
            {
                int x = ds.Tables[0].Rows.IndexOf(r);
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[x].Delete();
            }
        }

        void OcultarId()
        {
            dataGridP.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        private void DataGridP_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            CeldaIngresada = true;
        }

        private void DataGridP_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CeldaIngresada == true)
            {
                ActualizarTabla();
                CargarDatos();
                OcultarId();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Cualquiera que pueda brindar una ayuda se lo agradezco.

Answer (score 2):

Al principio del codigo defines la linea

```
string tipo = "Sociales";
```

pero en ninguna otra parte del codigo que nos muestras los cambias, es por eso que al evaluar los `if` que preguntas si es `Sociales`, `Apps`, `Carpetas` siempre resolvera por la unica opcion asignada

Deberias ver de cambiar la asignacion de esa variable para ue tomes otros valores

Comment: Pero sugieres que agregue otros strin. Por ejemplo: string tipo1 = "Carpetas" y asi o de que otra forma podria hacerlo

Comment: sugiero que vayas cambiando la asignacion de esa variable para que tome otros valores y no quede como una constante, o sea usar tipo="Apps" pero esto lo deberias ubicar en algun lugar del codigo donde definas que operas con otra tabla

Comment: Actualización:
Gracias a todos por la ayuda. CREO haber podido solucionar el problema, cambiando el string tipo = "Sociales" del comienzo por un string tipo = string.Empty;. Al hacer esto tuve que cambiar todos los else que debería identificarlo a "Sistema"

Comment: *Continuacion: else
{
Aquí el codigo
}
Por:
else if (tipo == "Sistema")
{
Aquí el codigo
}

Esto debí hacerlo ya que ocurría el mismo error pero esta vez con Sistema.

Al hacer esto no puedo comprobar si funciona los arreglos hechos, debido que al hacer este cambio me produce un problema en el metodo de OcultarId saliendome un mensaje de error: "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección.
Nombre del parámetro: index'"

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que el tipo = "Sociales" es una variable para saber que boton has pulsado por lo tanto tendrias que agregar un cambio de esta variable en cada boton:

```
    private void BtnSociales_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tipo = null //para no solapar con strings mas largos
        tipo = "Sociales";
        Cargar_CmdSociales();
        OcultarId();
    }

    private void BtnCarpetas_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tipo = null //para no solapar con strings mas largos
        tipo = "Carpetas";
        Cargar_CmdCarpetas();
        OcultarId();
    }

    private void BtnApps_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tipo = null //para no solapar con strings mas largos
        tipo = "Apps";
        Cargar_CmdApps();
        OcultarId();
    }

    private void BtnWebs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tipo = null //para no solapar con strings mas largos
        tipo = "Paginas Webs";
        Cargar_CmdWebs();
        OcultarId();
    }

    private void BtnSistema_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tipo = null //para no solapar con strings mas largos
        tipo = "Sistema";
        Cargar_CmdSistema();
        OcultarId();
    }
```